# JSF param not passed on the 2nd call

Tags: jsf

I have 2 buttons on the same page.

```
<p:commandButton action="#{testController.create}" value="Next">
    <f:param name="sid" value="#{sessionScope.userId}" />
</p:commandButton>

<p:commandButton action="#{testController.update}" value="Next">
    <f:param name="sid" value="#{sessionScope.userId}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

on my bean, both create and update method has this code:

```
Map<String, String> param = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
int id = Integer.parseInt(param.get("sid"));
```

on the first click either update or create, getting param sid works. but on the 2nd click, itl give me an exception on `int id = Integer.parseInt(param.get("sid"));`

i'm really confuse.. what am i missing here?

exception:

```
e = (java.lang.NumberFormatException) java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{sessionScope.userId}"
```

Comment: I guess you are getting `null pointer` as your  `param.get("sid")` is null. Where you getting this `userid` from.

Comment: on when user logs in, i put id to userId.

Comment: its a number, it actually works on the first call. example i click on create. it gives me the id no problem. but when i click on update after clicking create, it then gives me the error.

Comment: Which version of JSF are you using?

Comment: Are you really running the code you think you're running? The error suggests that you've actually a `<f:param name="sid" value="{sessionScope.userId}" />` where the `#` is missing from the `#{}`.